# GKE Gateway for load balancing creates wrong health check path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-gateway-api

I'm setting up GKE Gateway API in GKE cluster by following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/getting-started-with-gke-gateway-controller-ee45c3bc8996) and [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways).

The Gateway resource is working fine. It has created a Load Balancer resource on GCP and assigned a static IP address to it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: infra-ns
  labels:
    shared-gateway-access: "true"
---
kind: Gateway
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: external-http
  namespace: infra-ns
spec:
  gatewayClassName: gke-l7-gxlb
  listeners:
  - name: http
    protocol: HTTP
    port: 80
    allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: Selector
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            shared-gateway-access: "true"
```

The HTTPRoute resource apparently is working fine. It was recognized by the Gateway.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: other-namespace
  labels:
    shared-gateway-access: "true"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  name: myservice
  namespace: other-namespace
spec:
  ports:
    - name: myservice
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myservice
  type: NodePort
---
kind: HTTPRoute
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myhttproute
  namespace: other-namespace
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - kind: Gateway
    name: external-http
    namespace: infra-ns
  hostnames:
  - "demo.example.com"
  rules:
  - backendRefs:
    - name: myservice
      port: 80
```

I can see NEG was created for my service and the load balancer refers to it as a Backend Service.
The problem is the Health check showing my service as UNHEALTHY while I have tested the only pod beneath it and it's healthy.

What I see in GCP console is the wrong path for health checks. Manual edit doesn't work since it comes back to the same. And I haven't found anything to configure this path in HTTPRoute. Anyway, I belive it doesn't have to be configured since it should get the health path stated in livenessProbe/readinessProbe which is already present in the manifest of Deployment and it's **/health**, not **/**.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Why the health check path differs from the stated in liveness and readiness probes?

```
$ kubectl -n other-namespace describe deployment myservice

...
  Containers:
   myservice:
    Image:      myserviceimage:latest
    Port:       8080/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Requests:
      cpu:        1m
      memory:     1Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=10s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8080/health delay=2s timeout=3s period=2s #success=1 #failure=2
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the HealthCheck is set by default to the same port and path as the one your app serves traffic from.

If you need to customize healthCheck port/path or other Parameters you need to  use a HealthCheckPolicy https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-gateway-resources#configure_health_check

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76932097/368691

Answer (score 0):

I believe this the [part of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#limitations) that addresses specifically your case:

> GKE Gateway behaves differently than Ingress, in that Gateway does not infer health check parameters. If your Service does not return 200 for requests to GET /, or you have other tuned pod readiness checks, you need to configure a HealthCheckPolicy for your service.

You supposedly need a `HealthCheckPolicy` along the lines of:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: HealthCheckPolicy
metadata:
  name: NAME
  namespace: default
spec:
  default:
    logConfig:
      enabled: true
    config:
      type: HTTP
      httpHealthCheck:
        requestPath: /health
  targetRef:
    group:
    kind: Service
    name: YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

But for better or worse this changes the defaults (in case this matters):

```
checkIntervalSec: 15 -> 5
timeoutSec: 15 -> 5
healthyThreshold: 1 -> 2
```

Which you can override.

`logConfig.enabled` is optional. It lets you see the health checks that it makes:

```
$ gcloud logging read 'logName:healthchecks' \
    --freshness=10m \
    --project PROJECT_ID \
    --format=json \
  | jq '.[] | {
    targetIp: .jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.targetIp,
    probeResultText: .jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.probeResultText,
    detailedHealthState: .jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.detailedHealthState,
    timestamp}'

$ gcloud logging read 'logName:healthchecks' \
    --freshness=10m \
    --project PROJECT_ID \
  | yq '{
    "targetIp": .jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.targetIp,
    "probeResultText": .jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.probeResultText,
    "detailedHealthState": .jsonPayload.healthCheckProbeResult.detailedHealthState,
    "timestamp": .timestamp}'
```