# How to access logs of HealthCheckPolicy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In [google-cloud-platform](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform), when configuring `HealthCheckPolicy`, there is a field [`logConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-gateway-resources)  that I've enabled.

Where are these logs accessible?

I am trying to identify if the health check is failing.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to view them in log explorer.

To view logs, go to the Logs explorer.

Health check logs are indexed by instance group or network endpoint group.

To see all logs, in the Resource menu, select either GCE Instance Group or Network Endpoint Group, depending on the type of backend.

Alternatively, paste the following into the Query field. Replace PROJECT_ID with your project's ID.

logName="projects/gke-demos-345619/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fhealthchecks"

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-logging?_ga=2.11332340.-1126727214.1668238925#view_logs

Comment: Please note that logs are only generated for endpoint health transitions

Answer (score -1):

When you enable the logConfig field in a HealthCheckPolicy for a Google Cloud Platform service, the logs are accessible through Google Cloud Logging (formerly known as Stackdriver Logging). This logging service aggregates and stores logs from various GCP services, including health checks.

To access the logs:

1. Google Cloud Console:

- Go to the Google Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/
- Select your project.
- In the left navigation pane, go to "Logging" (under "Operations").
- You can use the filter bar to search for logs specific to your health checks.
  Filter by resource type, log name, or other relevant attributes.

2. Using gcloud CLI:

Run the following command to view health check logs:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=health_check"
```

You can use additional flags and filters to narrow down your search.
API Access:

You can also programmatically access the logs using the Cloud Logging API.
When reviewing the logs, you should look for log entries related to your health checks and any associated error messages. These logs will help you identify if the health check is failing and provide insights into why it might be failing.

Remember that the logs will include information about health checks across various Google Cloud services, so ensure that you use the appropriate filters and queries to narrow down to the specific health check logs you're interested in.